# Can't make a call from the A9G module

Tags: c, gprs

I have an A9G module. This module contains a 32-bit controller, GPS and GPRS. I'm flashing the standard ["call"](https://github.com/Ai-Thinker-Open/GPRS_C_SDK/tree/master/demo/call) example from [GPS_C_SDK](https://github.com/Ai-Thinker-Open/GPRS_C_SDK/tree/master) into it. When the module tries to make a call, the voice message “You have dialed incorrectly” appears. At the same time, I can call the module from my phone and everything will be fine. The SIM card in the module is working and you can make calls from it if you insert it into the phone.

The number was indicated in different formats - it did not help.

```
//#define DIAL_NUMBER "150....0062"
#define DIAL_NUMBER "79781234567"
//#define DIAL_NUMBER "+79781234567"
//#define DIAL_NUMBER "89781234567"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is way too specific for this site if you ask me... What is this number you are trying to call? Is it your number and you know it is working? Did you try to test it using AT commands before doing any programming? Here is some tutorials https://www.hackster.io/akarsh98/a9g-gps-gprs-module-tutorial-ai-thinker-at-commands-19df3f

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for the link to the tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I flashed the module with factory firmware (see how to do this [here](https://docs.ai-thinker.com/en/gprs_download)). Then I sent AT-commands to the module. I saw that he answered normally. Then I typed the command `ATD+79781234567` and the module made the long-awaited call. A call to a number in the format `89781234567` also works normally. But a number with a country code of `7`, but without `+`, no longer works, a message is displayed - the number was dialed incorrectly.

I flashed the `demo call` example into the module. Unlike previous compilations, I cleaned the files for compilation with the command `./build.bat clean call`. Then I compiled the project with the command `./build.bat demo call`, flashed the module and it made the long-awaited call. In this case, the call is made only if the country code is specified in the format `8` instead of `7` or `+7`.

Most likely, cleaning the files with the clean command helped. It was previously noted in another project that changes in the code did not change the behavior of the module in any way. And the `clean` command before compiling the project corrected this situation.